# ffmpeg in matlab on windows

Tags: matlab, ffmpeg

Is there a way to run ffmpeg commands in matlab on windows.

I know on Linux we can use the function system('...') to run any command but how can I do it on windows?

any idea would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [system](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) command should work just fine on a windows machine as well. For example, I ran the following with no issues on 64-bit Windows 7:

```
 system('ffmpeg -i C:\Users\Sam\demo.wav C:\Users\Sam\demo2.mpg')
```

Comment: Actually, I read that we can't use it on windows that's why I asked it but I tried it now and it works thanks